# Is there any good UAT online management website that is simple and effective?

Tags: software-development, software-testing

Is there any good UAT ([User Acceptance Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceptance_testing)) online management website that is simple and effective?
I have been looking for a while now to find a website out there to help me design tests and write documentation.

I know (Google) spreadsheet is an option but I'm looking for something more robust, ideally with notifications to help communication between developer and tester.